# Decide if const char* is a string literal or a variable

Tags: c++, winapi, string-literals

Is there any simple method to detect, if the parameter passed to a function(const char *argument) was a constant literal or a variable?

I'm trying to fix errors in some code, which is filled with IsBadWritePtr calls, which throw access violation exceptions if the parameter was a constant literal.

This was a terrible design stupidity but now I'm not allowed to change the awkward behavior.

Comment: I don't understand why it should matter. You can treat a pointer to the first element of an array of `const char` exactly the same, regardless of whether it was created by a string literal or not.

Comment: @sftrabbit I guess there are two potential issues: is it a null terminated string? And is it a pointer to a single `char`?

Comment: @MM.: Say what???? A literal is *not* a temporary. It is the *least* temporary type of object as it's lifespan is the whole program.

Comment: i don't know if it's of any reasonable use but a nice question!

Comment: You could pass this article around at work and see if it helps: [IsBadXxxPtr should really be called CrashProgramRandomly](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/09/27/773741.aspx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a different overload that will be a better match for string literals. This is not really *science* but just heuristics:

```
void f(const char* p); // potential literal
void f(char *p);       // pointer to non-const
```

Another idea would be taking advantage that literals are really *arrays*:

```
template <int N>
void f(const char (&_)[N]); // potential literal
```

Note that they don't quite detect *literal* vs. *not literal*, but rather some of the other features. `const char* p = createANewString(); f(p);` will resolve to `f(const char*)`, and `const char x[] = { 'A', 'b', 'c', '\0' };` will resolve to the template. Neither of them are *literals*, but you probably don't want to modify either.

Once you make that change, is should be simple to find out where each of the overloads is called.

This all works on the premise that the main function should not take the argument as `const char*` if it modifies it internally, and that the issue you are facing is because for backwards compatibility your compiler is allowing the call to a function that takes a pointer to non-const with a literal...

Answer (score 1):

<strike>I don't think there is an way to detect that not at-least without using some hackery.</strike>
Since the interface takes a `const char *` the responsibility of the function is to not modify the passed string anyways. You need to modify the implementation because it is simply incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

[`VirtualQuery`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366902) can be used to detect if the address is writable, read-only, or inaccessible. Examine the `State` and `Protect` members of the returned `MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION` structure to see if the memory is accessible and has the access you need.

Answer (score 0):

One VERY hackish way would involve checking if the pointer is in the .rdata segment.

Use `dumpbin /headers` after the build to retrieve the offset and length of the .rdata section, or parse the PE headers yourself. naturally, this is toolchain specific and generally a bad idea. Also, if the code needs to interoperate with DLLs, you'd have to check several executables and several .rdata segments.